# ClassCastException while implementing Many to many mapping with Liferay Service Builder

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to implement many to many mapping with liferay service builder. I have found one blog on [liferay savvy](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-service-builder-many-to-many_12.html) which explains how to implement it and provides a war file as well.
You can download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meeralferay/files/LiferayManyToManyPortlet/Many2Many-portlet.rar/download).

It gets deployed successfully and also allows you to create student and courses along with their mapping.

After adding some dummy data when I try to fetch courses based on student id with

```
List<Course> studentCourseList = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getStudentCourses(xxxx)
```

**where xxxx is student id captured from meera_students_courses table**.
and then iterating it over for loop

```
for(Course course : studentCourseList){
 ...
 }
```

I got `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.meera.db.model.impl.CourseImpl cannot be cast to com.meera.db.model.Course exception.`

I have checked the list size and it gives proper count. So iteration of the list where casting happens, gives above exception.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to [Liferay Many-to-Many RelationShip Throws Class Cast Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437080/liferay-many-to-many-relationship-throws-class-cast-exception)

Comment: I have checked, there are no duplicate classes. The error occurs while iteration over the list.

Comment: Whenever you can't typecast to a legitimate interface, you *definitely* have the interface on the classpath twice. It's just the error message that doesn't distinguish between the different versions. The VM tries to typecast to *the other* Interface but only prints the name, not the available interface's classloader identity. Look again, look harder. I guarantee that you have (at least) the Course interface twice. Inspect the global classpath, the WEB-INF/classes folder and all jars in WEB-INF/lib. You will find them eventually